# Reading XML file with PHP, XML file is not organized

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Hi all I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <car>
      <title>This is car</title>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <model>2018</model>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </car>

   <bike>
      <title>this is bike</title>
      <price>33.58</price>
      <description>Just the dummy description</description>
   </bike>
   <wheels>
      <title>this is wheel</title>
      <price>33.58</price>
      <description>Just the dummy description</description>
   </wheels>

   <bike>
      <title>this is bike</title>
      <price>33.58</price>
      <description>Just the dummy description</description>
   </bike>


</catalog>
```

I want to loop through the nodes and process the nodes accordingly. If it's a car, I need to pass the car details to some function and if it's a bike then I need to pass the bike details to the other function.

The point is to process the nodes based on the node type (car or bike or other).

PHP

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('data.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// move to the first <product /> node
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'product');

// now that we're at the right depth, hop to the next <product/> until the end of the tree
while ($z->name === 'product')
{
    // either one should work
    //$node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());
    $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

    // now you can use $node without going insane about parsing
    var_dump($node->element_1);

    // go to next <product />
    $z->next('product');
}
```

The above PHP code works fine if the nodes are products. I need to work with different nodes.

Comment: My question might sound stupid, but are you changing your hard-coded 'product' strings to whatever else you're trying to find?

Comment: we have to change that, but how to know which is next node?

Comment: Shouldn't the XmlReader take care of that? If you have `$z->next('bike')` it should give you the next `<bike>`, right?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel yes, but problem is the next element is not always bike only it can be anything. i mean the order is not fixed. we need to check manually.

Comment: Well, if the notes on the documentation page (https://www.php.net/manual/de/xmlreader.next.php#123774) can be trusted "_next() without parameters will bring you to the next sibling node on the same depth as the depth where the current cursor is._". The only thing would be to get to the first child with `while ($z->read() && $z->name === 'catalog');` However, after looking at the manual I think `XMLReader` is rather basic and another lib will give you a better API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just using SimpleXML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
foreach ($xml->children() as $product) {
    if ($product->getName() == 'car') {
        carFunc($product->title, $product->price, $product->model, $product->description);
    }
    if ($product->getName() == 'bike') {
        bikeFunc($product->title, $product->price, $product->description);
    }
    if ($product->getName() == 'wheels') {
        wheelFunc($product->title, $product->price, $product->description);
    }
}

function carFunc($title, $price, $model, $description) {
    echo "Car: $title: It's a $model selling for $price. In detail: $description\n";
}

function bikeFunc($title, $price, $description) {
    echo "Bike: $title: It sells for $price. In detail: $description\n";
}

function wheelFunc($title, $price, $description) {
    echo "Wheel: $title: It sells for $price. In detail: $description\n";
}
```

Output (for your sample XML)

```
Car: This is car: It's a 2018 selling for 44.95. In detail: An in-depth look at creating applications with XML. 
Bike: this is bike: It sells for 33.58. In detail: Just the dummy description 
Wheel: this is wheel: It sells for 33.58. In detail: Just the dummy description 
Bike: this is bike: It sells for 33.58. In detail: Just the dummy description
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jX0qd)